# Why is my function only applying SRC property only to the first uploaded image?

Tags: javascript, jquery

The function successfully creates N image elements with a class of `new-avatar-picture`, however, it only adds `SRC` property to the first image. I'm not getting any errors in the console either.

```
function displayInputImage(input) {

    var files = input.files;

    for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        var file = files[i];
        var reader = new FileReader();
        var x = document.createElement("img");

        reader.onload = function(e) {
            x.setAttribute("src", e.target.result);
        }

        reader.readAsDataURL(file);

        x.className = "new-avatar-picture";
        $('.upload-btn-wrapper').append(x);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue with your logic is due to the fact that `onload()` of the reader fires after the loop completes, so `x` will refer to the last element in the set. Hence that single element gets its `src` set N times.

To fix this you could use a closure:

```js
function displayInputImage(input) {
  for (var i = 0; i < input.files.length; i++) {
    var $img = $("<img />");
    (function($imgElement) {
      var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = function(e) {
        $imgElement.prop("src", e.target.result);
      }
      reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[i]);

      $imgElement.addClass("new-avatar-picture");
      $('.upload-btn-wrapper').append($imgElement);
    }($img));
  }
}
```

Alternatively you could create the new `img` elements only after the content of the file is read:

```js
function displayInputImage(input) {
  for (var i = 0; i < input.files.length; i++) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(e) {
      $('<img />').addClass('new-avatar-picture').prop('src', e.target.result).appendTo('.upload-btn-wrapper');
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[i]);
  }
}
```

Comment: This worked perfectly and I love that you've given an alternative as well.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do that is to give each image a new property, I call it `temp_src` so that the browser will not try to load the images right away.

Then in the `.onload` event, loop through all images that you have created and give each of them the proper `src` value, by copying it from its `temp_src` property.

Something like:

```
var reader = new FileReader();
function displayInputImage(input) {

  var files = input.files;

  for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    var file = files[i];

    var x = document.createElement("img");

    x.setAttribute("class", "temp_img");
    x.setAttribute("temp_src", file);

    reader.readAsDataURL(file);

    x.className = "new-avatar-picture";
    $('.upload-btn-wrapper').append(x);
  }

}

reader.onload = function(e) {
  var images = document.getElementsByClassName("tmp_img");
  images.forEach(function(img) {
    img.setAttribute("src", img.temp_src);
  });

}
```

Comment: I'm getting an error that reader is not defined ( the one used in reader.onload = function(e) {} ). I guess it makes sense since the reader is only defined in the for loop?

Comment: @Bobimaru yes, sorry I forgot about that. I will edit my answer